# notepad++ function list multi comment

Tags: c, regex, notepad++

All

My code (C file) has comment formats as below:

```
/* ... */
/* ...
 * ...
 */
```

In order to use Function list, I tried to modify functionList.xml as below:

```
<parser
displayName="C"
id         ="c_function"
commentExpr="(?x)
|   (?s:\x2F\x2A(.|\0x0A)*?\x2A\2F)  # regex - /\*(.|\n)*?\*/
```

But it doesn't work.
I tried the reg with find command on notepad++, and it worked.

I have no clue what happen.
Is there anyone who is kind to give me suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `x` added? `...\x2A\2F)` => `...\x2A\x2F)`

Comment: Hello, Gerhardh

Thanks for the remind.

I fixed the typo, but it still not worked.